# Select random split variable in JMeter

Tags: random, split, jmeter, beanshell, boolean-operations

While recording a test, when I select a checkbox then it returns 'On' as value. I have made my test plan in JMeter and now I need to randomly set value to this field as On or OFF on every request.

Can I achieve it using Beanshell scripting + Split or Random function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [__RandomFromMultipleVars](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars) function to random between values

> The RandomFromMultipleVars function returns a random value based on the variable values provided by Source Variables

If you put ON and OFF inside variables, e.g. inside `on` and `off` JMeter variables, then you can use:

```
${__RandomFromMultipleVars(on|off, rnd)}
```

It will save the random value inside `rnd` variable (second parameter) that can be used later as `${rnd}`

Another option to get same result is to add the following JMeter variables:

```
a_matchNr = 2
a_1 = on
a_2 = off
```

Then use function with JMeter variable prefix `a`:

```
${__RandomFromMultipleVars(a, rnd)}
```

Comment: Can I use ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(on|off, rnd)} by directly inserting the values instead of defining them as variables before, if yes how we can do it ??

Comment: @Satyajit no, you can't, this function only get values from variables

Comment: I have written this code ---> ${__split(${String1},value,|)}
${__RandomFromMultipleVars(value_1|value_2, rememberMe)}.....So now in this its extracting values from String1 and storing it as value_1, value_2,...value_n...now I have to use this value randomly and as these values are large in number I don't want to specify these in the __RandomFromMultipleVars function, so I am looking for a way to use these two functions in one line so that __RandomFromMultipleVars function will automatically get the values that the __split is creating.

Comment: @Satyajit You are just missing adding JMeter variable `value_matchNr` with value `2`

Comment: Actually, I want to use all this in one line, instead of specifying value_1, value_2 which I have done right now, I want to specify the array values generated by the split function. In short, I want to use split function in the random function and want the code in one line..Your help will be appreciated..

Comment: At last got it after running it multiple times, we can write it as - ${__RandomFromMultipleVars{__split(${String1},value,|)}, rememberMe)}.  Now even if the string will generate a 100 values after splitting, these values are passed to the __RandomFromMultipleVars which accept only variables value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[Starting from JMeter version 3.1 users are encouraged to switch to Groovy from Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

So you can do this using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(['On'\,'OFF'][new Random().nextInt(2)],)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Random Groovy]

Comment: At last got it after running it multiple times, we can write it as - ${__RandomFromMultipleVars{__split(${String1},value,|)}, rememberMe)}. Now even if the string will generate a 100 values after splitting, these values are passed to the __RandomFromMultipleVars which accept only variables value. 
@Dmitri T - Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

At last got it after running it multiple times, we can write it as - ${__RandomFromMultipleVars{__split(${String1},value,|)}, rememberMe)}. Now even if the string will generate a 100 values after splitting, these values are passed to the __RandomFromMultipleVars which accept only variables value.